# Can i use LayoutInflater.inflate() to open a new screen

Tags: android, android-layout, screen

I am relatively new to android, i need to open a new screen when a button is clicked.
As i checked the posts here they suggest using setContentView() or using an Intent.
In case 2 a new the screen is opened as a new Activity, as i dont want this to happen
could u tell me if i can use LayoutInflater to open a new screen, if so how to do this.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to open a new activity? What do you want to achieve? If you tell us more details we can help you providing an ideal solution.. that could be: opening a new activity, opening a dialog, replacing the activity content view, fill a layout container with an inflated view, etc..

Comment: I thought using LayoutInflater will also make the backbutton to work automatically.Also since the new screen has only TextView items i did not want it to open in a new Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question suggests that, there is no need to use LayoutInflater. Check this code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.basic_layout_1);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.basic_layout_1_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.basic_layout_2);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is all you need I think. But just in case I'm also posting XML files:

basic_layout_1.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello world! - Basic layout 1"
    android:textSize="32dip">
</TextView>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/basic_layout_1_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Basic layout 1 Button">
</Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

and basic_layout_2.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello world! - Basic layout 2"
    android:textSize="32dip">
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

//**EDIT**
What is important, this method of creating a new screen will cause that back button won't display basic_layout_1 but it'll exit your app (in example above). If you'd like to display previous screen you should override back button action (but in that case, why not use Intent?)